# c# winforms Child form load problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialog-based application.

I need to show a child window like this:

(1) First, the application's main dialog window will show up,

(2) then, a child dialog window will show up automatically on top of that.

You know, it is not enough to call the child window's `ShowDialog()` in the parent window's constructor or load event. Coz in those cases, the child window will appear first.

What should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use the event Shown of your main dialog, to show the child in front of you main dialog. This event is only raised once, when the main dialog is shown the first time. Also you should use the Show() (not ShowDialog) method and then call BringToFront() of your child dialog.

```
private void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  ChildDialog child = new ChildDialog();
  child.Show(this);
  child.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: what would be the problem with ShowDialog?

Comment: You can use ShowDialog, but then the ChildDialog is shown modular. Maybe this is fine for you.